# Error With prepareForSegue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to have it so that I can fill in 8 UITextFields in my ViewController view and then when I tap my button 'nextView' is called on. If all requirements are met (there is a UIImage for that string) I use self.presentViewController(...) to navigate to my next view. However, in that next view, my 8 images are not updated(image1 - image8). How can I solve this. Thank you. Below is my code and any advice would be great!

```
class ViewController : UIVewController {

    // field1 - field8 are defined here as UITextFields

    @IBAction func nextView(sender: UIButton) {

         if (my requirements are met) {

              let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

              let nextViewController : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View Two") as UIViewController

              self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

         } else {

               // nothing happens

         }


    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let Dest : ViewTwo = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewTwo

        Dest.c1 = field1.text! // c1 - c8 are strings in ViewTwo
        Dest.c2 = field2.text! // field1 - field8 are UITextFields in ViewController
        Dest.c3 = field3.text!
        Dest.c4 = field4.text!
        Dest.c5 = field5.text!
        Dest.c6 = field6.text!
        Dest.c7 = field7.text!
        Dest.c8 = field8.text!

    }

}

class ViewTwo : UIViewController {

    var c1 = String()
    var c2 = String()
    var c3 = String()
    var c4 = String()
    var c5 = String()
    var c6 = String()
    var c7 = String()
    var c1 = String()
    var c8 = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

           image1.image = UIImage(named: "\(c1)") // image1 - image8 are UIImageView s in ViewTwo
           image2.image = UIImage(named: "\(c2)")
           image3.image = UIImage(named: "\(c3)")
           image4.image = UIImage(named: "\(c4)")
           image5.image = UIImage(named: "\(c5)")
           image6.image = UIImage(named: "\(c6)")
           image7.image = UIImage(named: "\(c7)")
           image8.image = UIImage(named: "\(c8)")

           image1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 219, 80, 80) // these are the image’s dimensions
           image3.frame = CGRectMake(20, 302, 80, 80)
           image5.frame = CGRectMake(20, 385, 80, 80)
           image7.frame = CGRectMake(20, 468, 80, 80)
           image2.frame = CGRectMake(220, 219, 80, 80)
           image4.frame = CGRectMake(220, 302, 80, 80)
           image6.frame = CGRectMake(220, 385, 80, 80)
           image8.frame = CGRectMake(220, 468, 80, 80)

           self.view.addSubview(image1) // here I add the images to the view
           self.view.addSubview(image2)
           self.view.addSubview(image3)
           self.view.addSubview(image4)
           self.view.addSubview(image5)
           self.view.addSubview(image6)
           self.view.addSubview(image7)
           self.view.addSubview(image8)


    }

}
```

Comment: You should probably include the code that takes your c1 - c8 values and loads images from them.

Comment: Any errors / warnings from xcode?

Comment: `override fun viewDidLoad()`? Is this your real code?

Comment: Could it be that your next view is already loaded? I've tried this, putting a breakpoint in prepareForSegue and viewDidLoad and it works for me. If your next view is already loaded, try to move the code that update the images to viewWillAppear, and set a breakpoint there as well to verify the timings for each call.

Comment: Yes. I think that could be it +endavid because sometimes it also unexpectedly finds nil while unwrapping an optional because the view hasn't loaded and there for the value is still nil for it hasn't been unwrapped or downcasted. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the two ViewControllers with segue, not button to ViewController two then do the following:

```
 @IBAction func nextView(sender: UIButton) {
         if (my requirements are met) {
              performSegueWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier", sender: nil)
         } else {
               // nothing happens
         }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier" {
        let viewTwo = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewTwo

        viewTwo.c1 = field1.text! // c1 - c8 are strings in ViewTwo
        viewTwo.c2 = field2.text! // field1 - field8 are UITextFields in ViewController
        viewTwo.c3 = field3.text!
        viewTwo.c4 = field4.text!
        viewTwo.c5 = field5.text!
        viewTwo.c6 = field6.text!
        viewTwo.c7 = field7.text!
        viewTwo.c8 = field8.text!
}

    }

}
```

Comment: How do you create a identifier for a segue and how do you create one. Do I asign this : let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

              let nextViewController : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View Two") as UIViewController

              self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) to a segue.